# AppleScript does not run from calendar

Tags: applescript

I made the following code to open a website, insert some required text, click "View", and download the resulting document.  It runs perfectly if I manually click on it.  It also works if I schedule a calendar event to call it when I am sitting in front of my Mac.  I have tried every combination of keeping the display on/off and screen unlocked/locked.  For some reason, it doesn't seem to work at 5:30am and 2:00pm when I set it to run.  I have checked to make sure the disk and Mac are not going to sleep as well.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
--Quit Safari before the program starts
tell application "Safari"
    close every window
end tell

--empty "Downloads" folder
tell application "System Events"
    delete (every file of folder ("/Users/97pubs/Downloads"))
end tell

--opens DINS website
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.notams.faa.gov/dinsQueryWeb/"}
    activate
    ignoring white space
        tell front document to repeat until its text contains "About DINS"
        end repeat
    end ignoring
    log "Finished loading"
end tell

delay 2

--Function to press DoD banner on DINS website
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName

clickClassName("ui-state-default", 0)

delay 2

--Function to input ICAO abbreviations on the page
to inputByName(theName, num, theValue)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript " 
  document.getElementsByName('" & theName & "')[" & num & "].value ='" & theValue & "';" in document 1
    end tell
end inputByName

inputByName("retrieveLocId", 0, "kmaf")

delay 2

--Function to click "View NOTAMs" on page
to clickName(theName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('" & theName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickName

--Clicks "View NOTAMs" on page
clickName("submit", 0)

--Waits for next window to completely load before continuing
tell current application
    tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1
            repeat until (exists tab 2)
                delay 1
            end repeat
            ignoring white space
                tell front tab to repeat until its text contains "DINS Disclaimer"
                end repeat
            end ignoring
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

delay 1

--Clicks "Save all NOTAMs" on page
clickName("button", 1)

delay 2

--Waits for download to complete before continuing
set someFolder to "/Users/path/to/save/location/" -- put your download folder path here 
if not (waitForFilesToCopy into someFolder for (10 * minutes)) then
    display alert "Error with downloads" message "The downloads did not complete in the time allowed."
    if button returned of the result is "Cancel" then error -128
end if
to waitForFilesToCopy into theFolder for timeToWait
    (* 
    waits up to the timeToWait for files to be copied/downloaded to theFolder the test is based on the size of the folder not changing after several seconds the rough timeToWait may need to be adjusted if copying several files/folders parameters - theFolder [mixed]: the folder to check timeToWait [integer]: a maximum timeout value in seconds returns [boolean]: true if copy/download finished, false if timeout 
    *)
    set {theFolder, possible, interval} to {theFolder as text, false, 2} -- change the check interval as desired 
    tell application "System Events" to set currentSize to size of disk item theFolder -- get initial size 
    repeat (timeToWait div interval) times -- check every interval seconds 
        delay interval
        tell application "System Events" to set newSize to size of disk item theFolder -- recheck size 
        if (newSize is equal to currentSize) then
            if possible then -- no change since last time 
                return true -- success 
            else -- one more time... 
                set possible to true
            end if
        else -- update size & possible switch 
            set {currentSize, possible} to {newSize, false}
        end if
    end repeat
    return false -- fail (timeout) 
end waitForFilesToCopy

--Rename PDF to "5 Local NOTAMs.pdf"
tell application "System Events" to set name of file "/Users/path/to/save/location/temp.pdf" to "5 Local NOTAMs.pdf"

--Move NOTAMs to "CrewPapers" folder
tell application "Finder"
    move POSIX file "/Users/path/to/save/location/5 Local NOTAMs.pdf" to POSIX file "/Users/path/to/new/location" with replacing
end tell

--Close Safari and Preview windows
tell application "Safari"
    close every window
end tell
tell application "Preview"
    close every window
end tell
```

Comment: Try using cron or launchd perhaps.

Comment: This looks like a script assembled from a couple of separate scripts, which is an excellent way to construct scripts at the beginning, _as long_ as you then go through it and work out what you can merge/replace/simplify to both improve your scripting proficiency and to make your script more readable and easier to debug.  I don't have a solution to your specific query, but my first inclination would be to merge together all of your _Safari_ blocks (except the final one that closes the windows, which has to stay where it is), which includes getting rid of those handlers, which aren't needed.

Comment: I'd then merge the _System Events_ blocks (except the first one, which needs to stay where it is), plus convert the _Finder_ command to a _System Events_ one and merge that.  This would also mean breaking open the `waitForFilesToCopy` handler to merge with the other blocks, if that handler is really how you want to monitor for the downloaded file (I'd use a _Folder Action_ for this step).